# SSO Client Authentication in Laravel by using JWT

Tags: php, laravel, client, single-sign-on

I am trying to create a authentication system on Laravel based on JWT token. In the project, I am sending a login request to API and get Web Token if user succesfully login. I am using Guzzle package for the requests.

I search lots of article about it but none of them make sense.

My Controller :

```
public function sigin()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $url = "https://localhost:8080/users/login";     

    $user->email = Input::get("email");
    $user->password = Input::get("password");

    $json_data = json_encode($user);

    try{
        $response = $client->request('POST',$url,[
            GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => $json_data
        ]);

        // geting the Token in the response object. What should I do after get it 

    }
    catch(ServerException $exception)
    {
        $responseBody = $exception->getResponse()->getBody(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JWT you can retrieve a user from your database with this token. So put this token in the user's session and every time he does something "logged in" related, send his token to your API to check if it's him.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Putting the token into session is enough? How can i protect other routes unauthorized users. In other words, how can i build a such a guard system that user should logged in before see the page.

Comment: What I do is I check for the token, if it is not in session I redirect to the login page, if it is there, I check via JWT if it's a correct token. If it's not you also redirect to the login.